# output of a code in lambda python

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

The output of my code is in the below 3 print statements. which is a python code. when I run it in the terminal I do get the result because of `if __name__ == '__main__':`
Now when I put the same code block into lambda, it does not give any output because it is not calling or part of a lambda handler function. Can you please help me suggest on how I can do that.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOSTINFO = HostInfo()
    try:
    print 'trying'
    for hostname in list_resource_records(zoneid, region, profile):
      if '.'.join(hostname.strip('.').split('.')[-2:]) not in EXCLUDES and hostname.strip('.') not in EXCLUDE_HOSTS and is_ssl_listening(hostname, HOSTINFO):
        connect_ssl(hostname, HOSTINFO)
      except:
        print 'ok'

    print HOSTINFO.faulty
    print HOSTINFO.info
    print HOSTINFO.unknown
```

I now want use this code in a lambda and send the output via ses. I am looking for help to how to write it in the python ses code template?

```
ses = boto3.client('ses')

email_from = 'abc@xyz.com'
email_to = 'abc@xyz.com'
email_cc = 'abc@xyz.com'
emaiL_subject = 'ssl info'
email_body = 'output'


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = ses.send_email(
        Source = email_from,
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                email_to,
            ],
            'CcAddresses': [
                email_cc,
            ]
        },
        Message={
            'Subject': {
                'Data': emaiL_subject
            },
            'Body': {
                'Text': {
                    'Data': email_body
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: do you use aws lambda directly or over the serverless framework? If you use it directly, did you already do the `aws lambda create-function`?

Comment: the second part of your question I did not understand. I would suggest that you remove the second part for now and pose is as a separate question later, because currently this is are two separate questions in one, and that's confusing